# How to attach extra data to a TRC20 address?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I have a TRC20 address, e.g. `TBFoPS4fs27XLB4HPzhe7yaDwVxzcMbtZ1` on a page of my webapp so users can deposit their accounts in it.

When a User A sees the QR code with the address above, she can send some amount to it and see it in her account in my webapp.

Then a User B does the same.

How can I attach some metadata, like `userId=userA` to the address so it would go through to the network and I can see that this payment had been done by User A?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a unique trc20 address each time a user attempts to transact. Associate each address with a user.

Comment: That can work, but in this case if I have 100 users sending $1 each, I will have 100 addresses with $1 in each and to consolidate them I will need to move them to one address which will cost commissions and time for confirmations?